# UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a google script that I'm using in google spreadsheet to export some data from there. Recently they update the spreadsheet and I'm getting this error:

> UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Export');
```

Does anyone had this problem, any solution?

Thank you

Comment: As the error states, your solution is to "use HtmlService instead".

Comment: `UiApp` is a part of the older `UI service` which was deprecated in 2015. `UI service` will be completely shutdown on July 15, 2019 as stated in the [`Sunset Schedule`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset) so you need to upgrade your scripts to use the newer `HtmlService` instead. [There are guides and reference documentation you can use to learn about HtmlService on the offical Google Apps Script website.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Comment: There's an expectation that you do some research **before** you ask a question. If you had, you might have found [how to convert google app ui into html service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608938/). Possibly this Google documentation would also be helpful [Dialogs and Sidebars in G Suite Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs).

Answer (score 1):

Please start by learning the pretty basics of developing a web application using "vanilla" HTML/JavaScript/CSS. Mozilla Developers Network and freecodecamp.com among many others might be helpful.

Once you know the pretty basics of developing a web application, read [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html). Below is a very simple code for a web app including HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

```
function doGet(e){
  const css = '<style> p { color: blue;} </style>';
  const html = '<p>Hello world!</p>';
  const js = '<script>document.addEventListener("click",() => alert("Clicked!"))</script>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(css + html + js)
  .setTitle('My first web app')
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

Below is the above code adapted to be used to show a simple modal dialog in Google Sheets

```
function showDialog(e){
  const css = '<style> p { color: blue;} </style>';
  const html = '<p>Hello world!</p>';
  const js = '<script>document.addEventListener("click",() => alert("Clicked!"))</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(css + html + js), 
    'My first modal dialog'
  )
  .setWidth(300)
  .setHeight(100)
}
```

If you don't have time or will to learn, consider to use a no-code tool. As you are already using Google Sheets, Google AppSheet might be a good place to start specially if your spreadsheet already has data tables (sheet having column headers on the first row, values below each of them). To create a no-code app from Google Sheets, click on Extensions - AppSheet.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Related

- [Uploading file to spreadsheet shows "UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlServices instead"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57090349/1595451)