# var app = UiApp.createApplication() stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a message today:

> UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.

However I have no idea how to replace `var app = UiApp.createApplication()` as I have no coding experience.

```
function printPdf() { 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


var gid = sheet.getSheetId();


var pdfOpts = '&size=A4&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
//var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
var row2 = 80;
var printRange = '&c1=0' + '&r1=30' + '&c2=7' + '&r2='+row2; // B2:APn
var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts  + printRange;
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(300).setHeight(50);
app.setTitle('VSEE HR - Plik  PDF Gotowy');

var link = app.createAnchor('Download as PDF', url).setTarget('_new');

app.add(link);

ss.show(app);

}
```

My output was a popup window with link to download range as PDF.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) i.e. show attempts and specific coding issues to make a valid question on this forum.

UiApp has been set for deprecation since 2015 with today as the sunset date as displayed in the [sunset schedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset). As the error you're getting states, you can use [HtmlService as a replacement service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/). Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605042 as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The UIApp service of Google Apps Script is no longer available. You can however use the HTMLService service instead to load the modal window inside the Google Spreadsheet.