# Uploading file to spreadsheet shows "UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlServices instead"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-drive-api

This just happened yesterday.

I use this script for upload document to spreadsheet's cell till today I've got an error as

> UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
// upload document into google spreadsheet
// and put link to it into current cell

function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File...", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach ...", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("upload attachment into Google Drive");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  // these parameters need to be passed by form
  // in doPost() these cannot be found out anymore
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.createLabel('saving...');
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3-f0r3K_lCRRzJuRGI3Y2xxxx').createFile(fileBlob);
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');

  // write value into current cell
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
  var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
  var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  app.add(label);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UiApp class has been deprecated since 2014 [1] and recently they just shut it down (15 July) [2].

Now you have to use the HTML service classes [3][4].

I have a code that does something similar as yours (upload a file to Drive from a form), you can start from here, you need to bound the script to the spreadsheet and create a Index.html where you'll show your form:

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm" >
    Select File:
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="*" /><br>
    File name: <input type="text" name="fileName" /><br><br>
    Row position: <input type="number" name="position" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>
  <script>
   window.onload=func1;
  
  function func1() {
   document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });  
  }
  
   function upload(obj){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).withFailureHandler(close).uploadFile(obj);
   }   
   
   function close(e) {
       console.log(e);
       google.script.host.close();
   }
     
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('File')
      .addItem('Attach...', 'showForm')
      .addToUi();  
}

function showForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}

function uploadFile(obj) {
  var newFileName = obj.fileName;
  var rowNum = obj.position;
  var blob = obj.file;
  
  var upFile = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
  var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();
  
  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(rowNum,5);
  urlCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + fileUrl + '","' + newFileName + '")');
  
  return "It worked!";    
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/